# How to convert this select from Oracle to SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, equivalent

I need to know if the used `INTO` SQL Server and equivalent `ROWNUM` in SQL Server

```
SELECT 
    SERIE, CORRELATIVO
INTO   
    vSerie, vCorrelativo
FROM   
    SIG.SAF_SERIES_DOCUMENTOS_DET
WHERE  
    COMPANIA = pCompania
    AND MONTO = pMonto
    AND ESTADO = 'P'
    AND ROWNUM = 1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it, although you're missing an order by:

```
SELECT top 1
       @vSerit = SERIE, 
       @vCorrelativo = CORRELATIVO
FROM   SIG.SAF_SERIES_DOCUMENTOS_DET
WHERE  COMPANIA = @pCompania
 AND   MONTO = @pMonto
 AND   ESTADO = 'P'
```

If you need something else than the first row, You can also do a row_number() window function as a column into your select and use that to limit the data or use offset / fetch if you're in SQL Server 2012 or use top twice with asc / desc order by

Comment: Thanks for your help I served me much!